# Programmatically adding named ViewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I would like to add a number of ViewControllers but the number is not static. I know the following will create controllers.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as! vc1
let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as! vc2
```

But how would I go about dynamically naming them something like

```
for (vc = 1 to views.count) {
  vcname = "vc" + vc
  let vcname = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController")
}  as! vcname
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Whats the reason to do that?

Comment: It will be better if you store them in an array and do what you want with them. which will be same as vc1 vc2 etc .... as array objects

Comment: @derdida - the app needs to generate menu pages for users but each user has a bespoke number of pages based on their own preferences

Comment: But why you create multiple Controllers with the same identifier? Why check permissions for user, and create all Controllers in an Array of ViewControllers?

Comment: @derdida - the identifier just tells it what class of view to use as the basis for each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably be better off storing them in an array. For example:

```
let vcs = views.map { storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") }
```

Then access each view controller using array indices:

```
vcs[0], vcs[1], vcs[2]
```

And so on...

Comment: Sounds great - will give this a go. Thanks.

Comment: Sry PandaFox - no way to test this until my other issue with xCode is fixed since cannot build and run. Will get back to you when I have a solution for that and can run tests.

Comment: I'm now using PageMenu instead which builds the controllers in this way - so all seems good